# How can I retrieve JSONdata from ASP.NET and send it to jQuery? (implementing FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get JSON-data into a jQuery variable using ASP.NET (not MVC):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: GetEvents(start, end) //This line is invalid
    }
}
```

In MVC, it could just be `events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"`, which would call the CalendarController's GetEvents()-method.

But since I'm not using MVC I started following [this guide](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/) to try calling server-side methods from the client.

In the second step it tells me that I have to create a static method in order to do this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Message()
{
    return "Hello from the server-side World!";
}
```

But I need to be able to access non-static variables like `Session[]` inside the method, so I can't really see how this approach would work.

**Is there a better approach to getting JSON-data extracted from an aspx.cs-method that doesn't involve making direct server-side calls? Or is there a way for me to use the Session that I'm not aware of?**

Comment: You can access Session. Just use HttpContext.Current.Session.

Comment: I found this approach too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990565/fullcalendar-events-from-asp-net-ashx-page-not-displaying/3106900#3106900 but I don't know what's happening behind the scenes, so I don't know which approach is better, or if there's an even better one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly call server-side ASP.NET from jQuery object literal and return data to jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214669/how-to-properly-call-server-side-asp-net-from-jquery-object-literal-and-return-d)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling Session directly use HttpContext.Current.Session, or make it a static property in your page:

```
private static HttpSessionState MySession
{
  get
  {
    return HttpContext.Current.Session;
  }

  set
  {
    return HttpContext.Current.Session = value;
  }
}
```