# How to properly call server-side ASP.NET from jQuery object literal and return data to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, security

This question is heavily related to my former question: [How can I retrieve JSONdata from ASP.NET and send it to jQuery? (implementing FullCalendar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195445/how-can-i-retrieve-jsondata-from-jquery-in-asp-net-implementing-fullcalendar).

---

I'm trying to set the following [object literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php) in ASP.NET:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: GetEvents(start, end) //<-- This line is invalid
    }
}
```

The right-hand side of the invalid line above should contain a reference to JSON-data.

Since I assume this is a client-to-server-to-client call, I'm afraid there could be a potantial security issue if I do this the wrong way.

I found [a tutorial on calling a server-side method from javascript](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/) (it looks outdated to me) but is there a proper way to bind a jQuery object literal to data set dynamically in ASP.NET?

E.g. How do I create a response in ASP.NET that can only be called by logged in users, with appropriate rights (**each user** are only **allowed to edit 0 – * specific user-bound-events** in the calendar)? And how do I return that response to the jQuery object literal?

**EDIT:**

As requested, here's some pseudo-code for the `GetEvents(start, end)` method:

```
public JSONData GetEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    User user = HttpContext.Current.User;
    if(user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && IsValidTimePeriod(start, end)) {
        List<Event> events = EntityFrameWorkService.GetEventsFromDataBase(user, start, end);
        JSONData result = ConvertEventDataToJSON(events);
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

`JSONData` is whatever kind of JSON-data-object type should be returned, and `EntityFrameWorkService` is an imaginary class that has service methods between the GUI and Entity Framework.

Comment: This is confusing. In the title you're implying you're sending data **from server to client** but in the first line of your question you're implying **the opposite, so from client to server**... What is is then really?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Ah, I didn't realize that, I'll reword the title of the other question. Since I'm binding the object literal in jQuery code, I'm assuming it's executed at client side, which then means it calls client-to-server to get the data necessary.

Comment: Actually it was both. I needed to send data from client to the server, and then get it to respond back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve JSONdata from ASP.NET and send it to jQuery? (implementing FullCalendar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195445/how-can-i-retrieve-jsondata-from-asp-net-and-send-it-to-jquery-implementing-fu)

Comment: @RuneFS Not that I'm denying the accusation, but since the other question has an answer that points in a different direction than what I needed an answer to, and therefore can't edit the question, what other alternatives do I have than make another question that (hopefully) points in a direction closer to my (same) problem?

Comment: Edit the other question. It's common to reword the question when answers show the need for that (e.g. when the answers point in a completely different direction) or delete the question entirely

Comment: @RuneFS Not that this justifies anything, but I asked about this on meta and got the response to write a new question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145280/how-could-i-reformat-a-question-with-answers-already-provided/145281#145281. Maybe I wasn't specific enough in that question, but it's hard for me to know what I'm supposed/allowed to do if people tell me the two opposites are the right option.

Comment: Please add the code for the `GetEvents(start, end)` method.

Comment: @user1429080 Done (this message is only for notification, it'll probably be deleted later, to not fill up comment space).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, based on the link you included in the question, it seems like you are trying to get data from the server to the client using a page method. That's just one possible way of relaying data from server to client but I'll stick with it in this answer.

There are some important things to remember when implementing page methods:

1. The method must be `public` and `static`. This means that you cannot access for instance controls in the page the same way as when doing a post back.
2. The method must be decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute.
3. In order to get the proper javascript methods to call the page method, you must have a `ScriptManager` object on your page (not strictly true, you can call them using regular ajax as well, but the `PageMethods` object is added by the script manager):

   ```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"   
         EnablePageMethods="True">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   ```
4. When calling the method from script, use the `PageMethods` object. If you server side web method is:

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public static string Echo(string inputValue)
   {
       return inputValue.ToUpperInvariant();
   }
   ```

   then you can call like this (javascript):

   ```
   function echoSucceed(data) {
       alert(data);
   }
   function echoError(data) {
       alert('fail');
   }

   PageMethods.Echo("conver this to upper case", echoSucceed, echoError);
   ```

   Note that we pass function references to the javascript `PageMethods.Echo(...)`. Depending on whether the page method call succeeded or failed one of the functions will be called.

*But what about my issue you ask?*

First, create the page method in the code behind. Note that the response will automatically be serialized and deserialized so you can have the page method return for instance a list of events:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Event> GetEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end) { ... }
```

This list will become an array on the receiving end.

Next, create a helper javascript function that will help you call the page method. Something like this:

```
function getEvents(start, end) {
    var results;
    PageMethods.GetEvents(start, end, function (data) { results = data; }, function(data) { alert('Error while fetching events'); });
    return results;
}
```

Then, finally, call the method and pass the results to you calendar.

**Edit**: Some other options (alternatives to page methods):

- Plain old web service (.asmx)
- WCF service (.svc)
- Generic handler (.ashx), or more generally any custom HttpHandler, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx)
- Web API (the new kid in town, see [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api))

The exact details for how to use these vary depending on which one you choose. Tutorials for each can easily be found by seraching the web using suitable combinations of keywords.

Comment: Really great answer. Before accepting, I'd like it if you could list some of the other non-hack methods of doing this - other than using Page Method I mean.

Comment: @AskeB Added a short paragraph with some alternatives. But don't accept until you have tested that my answer has actually helped you solve the problem.

Comment: That may take some time since Visual Studio broke when I uninstalled SQL last night. I'll return if I have trouble applying your solution. In all cases I'll at least make sure to return before the bounty ends of course.

Comment: I decided to just give you the bounty since you made a great detailed answer, and I want to reward you for the effort. I'll just wait until I can test it to accept the answer. That seems to be the best solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! Hope it actually help you get forward.

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:'[YOUR_SERVER_URL]',
      data:{start:'01/01/2012',end:'31/12/2012'},
      success: function(data) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: data
        });
      } 
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm setting a lot (about 70 lines of code) of other object literals inside the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... })`-part so this will just nest it more than necessary I think. And it seems to me you've just moved my problem to know how to set "[YOUR_SERVER_URL]", without saying why this is a proper solution.

Comment: Your data should be transfered back from the server to the client, so a server call must be done and your calendar must be filled up on callback of this server call (asynchronuous way ...). YOUR_SERVER_URL is where the data will come from your server, once you've got those data back, you can instantiate your calendar.

Comment: I get that, but **1.** You haven't mentioned why this is a proper solution. **2.** You haven't told me how I can make a call in ASP.NET that will be called into your data-parameter. You've just showed me one way to make a server call with data and then assign the data, returned from the server, to the `events`-object literal. If you have a solution to my question, please elaborate _why_ this is a proper solution, and how to make the server response in the ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to generate some JSON from ASP.net into existing javascript, but another way is to just output the JSONData into a sort of service and use javascript/jquery to fetch the JSON:

1. Configure server to respond with JSON plain text using your GetEvents method when it hits "http://yourserver/events/?start=somedate&end=someotherdate".
2. Make a jquery call using: `$.getJSON("http://yourserver/events/?start=somedate&end=someotherdate")`;

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but judging from your link (`http://yourserver/?start=somedate&end=someotherdate`) you're talking about is using the [Controller in MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-controller) to respond to data. I'm using [Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview). If I'm wrong, please elaborate your answer.